# Mixitup фильтр. Настроить сортировку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Помогите пожалуйста с фильтром mixitup
Как сделать так что-бы при перезагрузке страницы, фильтр сразу сортировал по Первому залу и 14 числу??
Сейчас при перезагрузке страницы, он показывает все числа и залы

[ссылка на код](https://codepen.io/oleg-z-zin/pen/bGdNaaK)

```
<form class="controls" id="Filters">
  <!-- We can add an unlimited number of "filter groups" using the following format: -->

  <fieldset>
    <h4>Зал</h4>
    <button class="filter" data-filter=".qw">Первый зал</button>
    <button class="filter" data-filter=".qe">Второй зал</button>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <h4>День</h4>

    <button class="filter" data-filter=".as">14 число</button>
    <button class="filter" data-filter=".ad">15 число</button>
  </fieldset>


</form>

<div id="Container" class="container">
  <div class="mix qe as">второй зал 14 число</div>
  <div class="mix qe ad">второй зал 15 число</div>
  <div class="mix qw as">первый зал 14 число</div>
  <div class="mix qw ad">первый зал 15 число</div>
</div>
```

Наверное задача мега простая... но я не шарю в js